# Emulator for Android 12 preview no connection

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-12

I have installed the Android 12 Preview emulator. I had a lot of problems because the emulator was crashing on start up but after uninstalling and installing it again and restarting the machine etc, I managed to start it.
The problem I have now is that the internet connection does not work.
All the other emulators work fine.
I have tried to start the emulator from the command line to set the dns

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_5_API_S -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

What I get is that the network still does not work and I can see a lot of logs:

> vqParseGuestToHostRequestLocked:734 {src_port=2489684015 dst_port=4294967295} unexpected dst_port

> vqParseGuestToHostRequestLocked:734 {src_port=2489684016 dst_port=4294967295} unexpected dst_port

> vqParseGuestToHostRequestLocked:734 {src_port=2489684017 dst_port=4294967295} unexpected dst_port

> vqParseGuestToHostRequestLocked:734 {src_port=2489684018 dst_port=4294967295} unexpected dst_port

This is the emulator that I'm using:

```
Name: Pixel_5_API_S
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64)
Path: /Users/username/.android/avd/Pixel_5_API_S.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level S)
Skin: pixel_4
SD Card: 512M
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: pixel_5
hw.lcd.width: 1080
image.androidVersion.codename: S
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 30
tag.id: google_apis
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.camera.front: emulated
avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 5 API S
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.ramSize: 1536
PlayStore.enabled: false
fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
hw.cpu.ncore: 4
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.dPad: no
hw.lcd.height: 2340
vm.heapSize: 256
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-S/google_apis/x86_64/
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: virtualscene
AvdId: Pixel_5_API_S
hw.lcd.density: 440
hw.arc: false
hw.device.hash2: MD5:3274126e0242a0d86339850416b0ce34
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

[image]

Comment: `have installed the Android 12 Preview emulator. I` Can you give a link as all emulators i can find are 11/S.

Comment: `image.androidVersion.api: 30` 30==R. Where is the 12?

Comment: @blackapps you need to follow the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/get#on_emulator

Comment: @blackapps then you will find the emulator in the x86 tab

Comment: Do you see a 12 there? I only see S.

Comment: same problem here. Up to Android 11 the emulators are working fine. Seeing the same error flodding in the logs. Fedora Linux, Studio beta channel

Comment: @blackapps I added a screenshots of what I see

Comment: yeah, same problem here. The problem has appear after Android S Preview last update to revision 5.

Comment: @kingston https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190788878

Comment: @kingston the status of the bug still to new :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190923231), the Android S beta 2 emulator image depends on a newer version of the emulator itself (without explicitly requiring it). The problem should be resolved by installing a newer 30.7.3 version of the emulator from the [canary channel](http://tools.android.com/preview-channel).

---

**Update 2021-06-23:** Emulator 30.7.4 is now available in the stable channel.

Comment: Wonder if Artic Fox beta is enough, or is canary really needed?

Comment: The Emulator version 30.7.3 is needed to get it working for me.

Comment: @JohanPaul I used both Artic Fox beta and the one from the canary channel and they kept failing. Did anyone have more luck?

Comment: @kingston I updated to 30.7.4 from the canary channel and it did the trick. Try creating a new emulator after the update

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using a couple of things.

1. Changing the Graphics option on the Android Virtual Device to Software instead of Automatic or Hardware.
2. Upgrading my system's Java version from 8 to 11.

To fix this, first check the java version installed on your system by using:

```
java -version
```

In case you see Java 8, try to install Java 11 from OpenJDK (https://jdk.java.net/archive/) and then you can add aliases like this in your ~/.bash_profile file:

```
export JAVA8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)

alias java8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA8_HOME'
alias java11='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA11_HOME'
```

Then you can easily switch to Java 11 by using:

```
java11
```

And now try to open the emulator again. It should work.